# How to add relationship to this two tables when there is a id and prefix in the primary key?

Tags: mysql, database

I can't figure out how t link these two tables. Can anybody help?
I want to add a relationship in these two tables but since I used id and prefix as primary key, it doesn't accept it as a foreign key. I always get "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".

```
CREATE TABLE Donor (
    id int(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    prefix varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D',
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, prefix)
  );
    
INSERT INTO Donor (name) VALUES
('Product #1'),
('Product #2');

SELECT CONCAT(prefix,id) as "DonorID", name FROM Donor;

CREATE TABLE Blood_Type (
    btid int(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    btprefix varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BT',
    id int(3) NOT NULL,
    prefix varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D',
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (btid, btprefix),
    foreign key (id, prefix) references Donor(id, prefix)
  );
    
INSERT INTO Blood_Type (name) VALUES
('Blood #1'),
('Blood #2');

SELECT CONCAT(btprefix, btid) as "bloodID", name FROM Blood_Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ZEROFILL` to your id :

```
CREATE TABLE Blood_Type (
    btid int(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    btprefix varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BT',
    id int(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    prefix varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D',
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (btid, btprefix),
    foreign key  (id, prefix) references Donor(id, prefix)
  );
```